# Mongo db role with find privilege can insert and modify

Tags: mongodb, user-roles

I've created role designer for database M that want to just read col1 collection
but when I login to database it can insert and find and modify col1, and even create new collection and `findAndModify` col1, but can't remove any data or collection.

What's the problem, I just want to read col1 and do not want to modify col1, and want to insert and read and update other collections and don't want to delete any data from other collections too.

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "designer",
     privileges: [ 
       { resource: { db: "M" ,collection:"col1" }, actions: [ "find"] },              
     ],
    roles:[]    
   },
   { wtimeout: 5000 }
)

db.createUser( { user: "U",
                 pwd: "123456",
                 roles: [ { role: "designer", db: "M" }]},
               { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } )
```

Comment: @marc_s still nobody answer, just editing ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about MongoDb - only fixed glaring typos and cleaned up the post a bit to make it more presentable

Comment: still no answer?